# The equation $az+b \bar{z}+c=0$ has exactly one solution if $|a| =|b|$. It is true or false?

Tags: complex-analysis

The equation $az+b \bar{z}+c=0$ has exactly one solution if  $|a| =|b|$. It is true or false?

Comment: Consider a = 1, and b = 1.  Note that $z + \bar{z} = 2\Re{z}$

Comment: What is a solution in your case? That it is true for all $z$ or is a singe $z$ enough ?

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**
$$az+b \bar{z}+c=0$$
if $|a|=|b|$ then $b=\pm a$

Let $b=\pm a$ then $a(z \pm \bar z)+c=0$

So infinite number of points would satisfy the equation

**Long Answer**
$$az+b \bar{z}+c=0$$
Let $z = x+iy$
$$\Rightarrow az+b \bar{z}+c=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a(x+iy)+b (x-iy)+c=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a.x+i.a.y+b.x-i.b.y+c=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x(a+b)+iy(a-b)+c=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x(a+b)+iy(a-b)=-c$$

If $c$ is real, then $a=-b$ or $|a|=|b|$, so any $y$ would fit the equation.

If $c$ is imaginary, then $a=b$ or $|a|=|b|$, so  any $x$ would fit the equation.

if $c$ is complex $A+iB$
$$a+b=A$$
$$a-b=B$$
$$a=(A+B)/2$$
$$b=(A-B)/2$$
$$|a| \ne|b|$$

So if $|a|=|b|$, there will be $\inf$ solutions of $z$
Thus the answer is false.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a=b=c=0$ Than every $z$ is a solution of your equation.

Else write 
$$|a| e^{i \phi_1} |z| e^{i \varphi} + |b|e^{i \phi_2} |z| e^{-i \varphi} + c= 
  |az| (\exp(i( \phi_1+ \varphi)) + \exp(i(\phi_2-\varphi)))+c=0$$

Comment: And on the other end of the spectrum, take $a=b=0,c\neq 0$, in which case *no* $z$ is a solution.

Comment: By the way, $z = |z|e^{i\phi}$ and not $z = |z|e^{\phi}$.

Comment: @J.H. oh right bad typo

Answer (score 1):

$az+b \bar{z}+c=0$

Taking $z=x+iy$

$a(x+iy)+b(x-iy)+c=0$

$\implies x(a+b)+iy(a-b)+c=0$

$\implies x(a+b)+c=0$ and $y(a-b)=0$

$\implies x=\dfrac{c}{a+b},y=\begin{cases} 0,&\text{if $a\neq b$}\\\text{arbitrary real no},&\text{if $a=b$}\end{cases}$

For example, $\dfrac{1}{4}+i$ and $\dfrac{1}{4}+2i$ are two different solutions of $2z+2\bar{z}+1=0.$